# Creating same size and quality MBTiles for all zoom levels with one image

Tags: qgis, raster, tiles, zoom, mbtiles

I have downloaded a world map from QGIS in TIFF format. Also, I have world map sample in MBTiles format. I need world map 0-19 zoom levels. I have tried to convert tiff with 0-19 to MBTiles, but QGIS crashes. I have used processing plugin, raster tools to convert file to MBTiles.

Is there any way to create low res world 0-19 zoom level MBTiles map with just a single image ? I know how it works but for now quality and squares does not matter.

Comment: The whole world at zoom level 19 takes 274,877,906,944 tiles (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_disk_usage). The size of your MBTiles file would be hundreds of terabytes. It does not make any sense to oversample your world map up till Z19. Don't oversample beyond the native resolution but make your client to stretch that lower lever tiles.